# number of ways of constructing $n\times2$ rectangle from a $1\times2$ rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

You are given  $1\times2$ rectangles and you have to construct an $n\times2$ rectangle from it. Tell the number of ways of constructing $n\times2$ rectangle from a $1\times2$ rectangle

Comment: Do we have copies of it?

Comment: yes u have copies of 1*2 rectangle

Comment: and u have to construct from  that n*2 rectangles ...example

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to construct the $2\times n$ rectanlge from $1\times 2$ rectangles. Then it is obvious that $a_1=1$ and $a_2 = 2$. Try to figure out what $a_{n}$ is with regard to $a_{n-2}$ and $a_{n-1}$. That is, find the reccurence relation to describe $a_n$.

Comment: cAN U EXPLAIN IT MORE ...pLEASE AND THANKS

Comment: Not until you show you put some effort into solving the task.

Comment: I will, as soon as he shows some effort. I will not, however, solve the whole thing while someone just keeps writing "write more, write more!"

Comment: What would you get for $n=12$? I get $720$...

Comment: @draks... Well, the recursive equation is $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$, so you can just calculate $a_{12}$ by calculating the other values.

Comment: which is Fibonacci $F_{12}=89$?

Comment: No, because the sequence starts with the second Fibonacci number